# Google Datastream (mysql to bigquery), no is_deleted field with tables with primary key

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, data-stream, google-datastream

I am using datastream in GCP with MySQL source and BQ destination. I have noticed that if the source table has a primary key defined, then the datastream metadata fields do not include the "is_deleted" column.

Also, the BQ table (when queried) replicates the MySQL table instead of all the events that occurred.

(Example; if my MySQL table has 5 rows and I modified row 1 and deleted row 2); I would expect 7 rows in the BQ table (5 rows + 1 modification + 1 deletion). However, when I query (SELECT * FROM ) the BQ table, it only has 4 rows (replicates the resultant MySQL table)).

The above example works as expected if the source table DOES NOT have a primary key.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [faq](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/faq),

> Datastream writes the change events directly to the BigQuery dataset where the changes are merged continuously (UPSERT) with the existing data.

Datastream uses upsert for updating table. When a primary key exists, bigquery can upsert based on the primary key. So the table will maintain the same as the source table. When primary key doesn't exist, I guess bigquery cannot merge rows.

But I don't know if there are settings that can change this behavior.